# excel can VBA UDF output formatted text?

Tags: string, excel, vba, format, user-defined-functions

Is there a way to return a string from an UDF formatted? For example I would like first two words to be bold, the rest not.

Comment: If you get an answer that works, please accept it by clicking the check mark that appears on the upper left of the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are not allowed to alter the formatting of the worksheet. That being said, Sub() can and you can easily write a Sub routine that does this - it just means you'll have to run the macro (like using F8) instead of entering it as a formula inside a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't apply rich text formatting to the result of a formula.